# Why absolutely positioned tables do not calculate width/height based on their top/left/right/bottom values?

Tags: css

I have an outer `<div>` that is relatively positioned and with a defined size. Inside it, I have a `<table>` object that is absolutely positioned and with `top`, `left`, `right` and `bottom` set to zero. I expected the table to be expanded to obey the top/left/right/bottom constraints, however, this is not what happens. Instead, the table dimensions are calculated based on its contents.

If I use an inner `<div>` instead of a `<table>`, then it works as I expected. On the other hand, if I put `display: table;` at the inner `<div>`, then it behaves exactly like a table.

My question is: **why does it happen?** Where in the specifications is this behavior defined? Or is it a bug in browsers (very unlikely)?

I've checked the [CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/), I've read the sections [9.7 Relationships between 'display', 'position', and 'float'](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo), [10.3.7 Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width), [17 Tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html). I've also checked the [position CSS attribute in Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position). I've also searched in StackOverflow. And, still, I can't find an explanation on why tables behave like this.

See a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LgCDE/2/
I can reproduce the results on both Chrome 27 and Firefox 20.0.

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>Hey!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="table">Hey!</div>
</div>
<div class="box">
    <div class="table" style="display: table;">Hey!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.box {
    position:relative;
    border: 2px dashed red;
    background: #800;
    width: 100px;
    height: 50px;
}

.table {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    border: 3px double blue;
    background: #CCF;
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[image: Three blocks are shown, the top-most is a table element, the middle one is a div element, the bottom-most is a div element with display: table.]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer, I believe, lies in the CSS2.1 specs, specifically [Section 17.5.2: Table width algorithms: the 'table-layout' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#width-layout) (emphasis mine):

> Note that this section overrides the rules that apply to calculating widths as described in section 10.3. In particular, **if the margins of a table are set to '0' and the width to 'auto', the table will not automatically size to fill its containing block**. However, once the calculated value of 'width' for the table is found (using the algorithms given below or, when appropriate, some other UA dependent algorithm) then the other parts of section 10.3 do apply. Therefore a table can be centered using left and right 'auto' margins, for instance.

As you noted, with `width` set to `auto`, the width will be based on the contents, rather than the containing block.

There's also this line at the end of that section, although I'm guessing it hasn't happened yet:

> Future updates of CSS may introduce ways of making tables automatically fit their containing blocks.

Comment: There is also: *However, if the table is a block-level table ('display: table') in normal flow, a UA may (but does not have to) use the algorithm of 10.3.3 to compute a width and apply fixed table layout even if the specified width is 'auto'.* But it does not apply to this case for two reasons: it is not in normal flow, and browsers did not implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find any technical reason, but I think it makes sense when you think about what a table is supposed to be. The default display for a div is block, a chunk of content. Thus, it defaults to 100% in width. A table just expands to your content.

In your example, if you set .table to have a width of 100%, it will act the same.